# Pseudo element not affected by parent overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a skewed section with a picture background. The point is that I want this background with the skew of the parent cancelled. I tried to achieve this with a pseudo-element.

I don't understand why the overflow:hidden of the parent does not affect the ::after element. Could someone help?

```
.main::after {
  content:"";
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1420310414923-bf3651a89816?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=47f355d1a7520ad5f1718e9388dd4967");
  background-size:cover;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width: 110%;
  height:110%;
  transform: rotateZ(5deg) skew(5deg);
```

Here is the code and example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWEZxK

Thanks in advance

Chris.

Comment: is this what you're trying to achieve? http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/GogQev?editors=110

Comment: Yes, that's it. Sorry I did not have any notification for your message.

Comment: do you want me to post that as answers so you can mark that as solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

**Demo**

```css
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
/*height:100%;*/
}

body {
  background: #272727;
}

section {
  width:100%;
  min-height:500px;
  transform: rotateZ(-5deg) skew(-5deg);
}
.main {
  background-color: crimson;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
 }

.main::after {
  content:"";
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1420310414923-bf3651a89816?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=47f355d1a7520ad5f1718e9388dd4967");
  background-size:cover;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
left:-10%;
  right:-10%;
  top:-10%;
  bottom:-10%;
  transform: rotateZ(5deg) skew(5deg);
  z-index:2;
 }
```

```html
<section class="main">

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. So I guess it's a Z-index issue. I'll have to understand that.

Answer (score -1):

the after pseude needs the same deffinitions as parent element .. to we just repeat declarations..

http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/GogQev?editors=110

```
overflow:hidden;
transform: rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg); }
```

cheers :)